# Android Maven in Eclipse - Creating an Activity

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, m2eclipse, m2e

Every time I create an Activity in Eclipse using the Android-Maven plugin, the Activity automatically gets created under src rather than src/main/java.

For example, I have the src/main/java source file in the Eclipse Package Explorer. Under the source folder I have the com.example.package.name package. I right click the package and select "New" -> "Other" and select "Android Activity". After putting in all the information regarding the new Activity I click "Finish". The problem is, when Eclipse creates the Activity and updates the Manifest, it puts the new Activity under "src/com/example/package/name" and indicates that path in the Manifest. It should be placing the Activity under "src/main/java/com/example/package/name".

This behavior is correct and expected for ant-based Android builds, but not Maven, as Maven requires a src/main/java and src/main/test folder before it even compiles and launches your Android application! Maven will still compile and build, it's just awkward and does not follow the primary Maven "Convention over Configuration" principle: (http://www.sonatype.org/maven/why)

Anyone else having these sorts of issues? Is manually relocating these Activities and manually updating the Manifest the only method to deal with this?

Comment: Either put everything under `src/main/java`, or configure Maven to use `src/` instead of `src/main/java`, do not use `src/com/..` and `src/main/java/com/..` at the same time.

Comment: Unfortunately this sounds like a convention hard-coded into the ADT: although you have the flexibility to move source folders around in the Eclipse classpath it sounds as though the ADT Activity Wizard doesn't respect these. You might want to raise a bug/patch with the ADT-dev team?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I'm new to android but really like Maven. Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [m2e-android](http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/) - An Android Configurator for M2E Maven Integration for Eclipse.

As you can see, it allows you to work with the standard maven directory layout :

[image]

Comment: Yup! That's what I'm working with currently... which is why I'm so confused about why it's building Activities into the src/ folder.

Comment: Did you start a new project or convert an existing one ?

Comment: I pulled it in from a remote git repository... on the git repo in the "Git Repositories" view I right clicked on the cloned repo and selected "Import Maven Projects"

Comment: it was probably configured to use src instead of src/main/java in the remote git repo. (what's in the pom.xml -> build -> sourceDirectory ?

Comment: build -> sourceDirectory does not currently have an entry (does not exist in the pom.xml)